# Cannot properly loop solver inside a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and only know enough to usually do simple things. I've searched for answers and gotten clues, but the code I'm writing seems so simple it should be easy to fix.

I wrote the explicit code for one line in my sheet: it works fine every time. The problem is I have thousands of lines I'd like to iterate with the same solver function in many rows and it doesn't work.

Here's the code that works and the code that doesn't. Any help getting to an iterative solution would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
Sub Multiple_Solver()

Dim Fit_Value As Double
Dim Count1 As Integer


Count1 = 3
'solve for MA0
Fit_Value = Cells(Count1, 18)
Cells(Count1, 23) = 5 'this is $W$3 forced to an initial value
'explicit code that works follows
Application.Run "SolverReset"
Application.Run "SolverOk", "$M$3", 3, Fit_Value, "$W$3"
Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
'This Code DOESN'T work..... not sure why; tried to make it the same structure.
'set up variables needed
Dim Fit_Value As Double
Dim Count1 As Integer

Dim MAx_eqn, FinalZ As Range

'loop to populate many rows
For Count1 = 3 To 3 'number of solutions starting at row 3; 
'solve for MA0:
Set MAx_eqn = Cells(Count1, 13) 'this is cell with equation MA0
Fit_Value0 = Cells(Count1, 18) 'this is the retest value MA0
Set FinalZ = Cells(Count1, 23) 'this is the initial/final step value for MA0
Cells(Count1, 23) = 5 'force initial value
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:=MAx_eqn, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=Fit_Value0,   ByChange:=FinalZ
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

Next Count1



End Sub
```

Comment: `For Count1 = 3 To 3` this is going nowhere. It should be more like `For Count1 = 3 To 100` or something like that.

Comment: code actually dims Fit_Value0 in part that doesn't work; just forgot to clip it into query.

Comment: Thanks, Bernie. Using Count1 = 3 to 3 so that it runs only one line. Once it runs properly it's simple to increase it to 100 or 1000.

Comment: How does your code fail?

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question: what is the easiest way to duplicate the code that works using in a loop so I can run many lines (say 100-1000)? I like application.run better than directly running solver because you don't need to enable Solver. I'm just clumsy with VBA and don't know how to introduce the key cells as looped cell references.

Answer (score 0):

OK--maybe this will help someone else. I found this on another forum, and it  works.

```
Sub Solve_Cells()
'Run interations of solvers on many rows
Dim Count1 As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim Fit_Value As Double

Count1 = 3
For Each rng In Range("A3:A4") 'explicit for first two rows; can fix later to bring in carrier of number of rows
    Fit_Value = Cells(Count1, 18) ' load retest value to solve for from spreadsheet
    Cells(Count1, 23) = 5 ' force to solve on negative side of curve with reset initial value
    Application.Run "SolverReset"
    Application.Run "SolverOk", rng.Offset(0, 12).Address, 3, Fit_Value, rng.Offset(0, 22).Address
    Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
    Count1 = Count1 + 1
    Next rng

End Sub
```